# Android: how to disable an activity without crashing the app

Tags: android, adb

I know `adb shell pm disable <activity_name>` can prevent an activity from launching. But it turns out whenever I click the button that can launch the disabled activity, the app just crashed.

I hope the event that launches the disabled activity just does nothing, rather than crashing the app. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: The app developer has not handled activity not being found, so it crashes! It can simply prevented by catching the related exception. (I assumed you are not the app developer.)

Comment: @mahdi No, I am not the developer. I am asking this question from a black-testing perspective.

Comment: If the app crashes then the only way is to decompile the app, change the calls to the mentioned activity and recompile and resign the app.

Comment: @RichardHu In this case, there is no way for you to be able to prevent the crash, unless you de-compile and build it again, which IMHO it is not recommended.